# Dialogflow Send message without user intent

Tags: javascript, node.js, android-intent, bots, dialogflow-es

Looking to find a way to make dialogflow send a message to the user every x minutes,

without any intent or user action required.
is there a way to do this? maybe making a custom event?

If someoneone could explain if this is possible that be great.

im also using nodejs for my bot.

Answer (score 2):

No, this isn't possible. Dialogflow is designed for conversational exchanges.

Answer (score 1):

Dialogflow is a NLP engine, It's designed to respond to the user input(either a text input, or an event request).

One way to do resolve this issue is, from the Client side run a thread that will send event request asynchronously after every x minutes, and the bot will reply with a message.

Visit https://dialogflow.com/docs/events/custom-events for more information.

Please reply if you need any more information/example on this.

Answer (score 0):

As @Prisoner said it isn't possible to do with dialogflow itself but you can look into assistant push notifications where you can get permission from user to send notifications and if user allow then you can send notification periodically. You can find more in [docs](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates/notifications).